# How can I add line numbers to a textarea using an ordered list?

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea, html-lists

I have a textarea, and I want line numbers made from an ordered list to be to the left of it and to have them correspond with the scrolling and CSS of the textarea.

[image: visual of what it should look like]

Here is the HTML code:

```css
#objtext{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:30%;
  height:70%;
  background-color:#eeeeee44;
}

#linenumbersdiv{
  color:brown;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande",Verdana;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:40px;
  height:70%;
  background-color:lime;
  margin-left:-10px;
  padding:0px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  margin-top:0;
  margin-bottom:0;
  padding-left:0;
  
}


#linenumberslist{
  font-size:10px;
  display:block;
  margin-top:0;
  margin-bottom:0;
  margin-left:0;
  margin-right:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="linenumbersdiv">
      <ol id="linenumberslist">
        <li id="theone">this could be individually colored!</li>
        <li>ahh</li>
        <li>AHHHH</li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <textarea id="objtext"></textarea>
```

I can't figure out the CSS to make the ordered list elements line up with the default CSS of the textarea. Once I figure out that, I can probably figure out the rest using some code I once made to make a chat go to the bottom on each new message.

I also want to be able to maintain the ability to color the text of an individual line number, so that ruled out another textarea, and I also don't want to use jQuery or any other plugins.

[This](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp) link doesn't help me, when I look at the CSS of the textarea and the ordered list, and then try to make them the same from there, it doesn't work.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp

The question: **Is there a way to reproduce the CSS of a textarea into an ordered list such that the lines line up?**

Comment: You can not match the scroll position between the two using CSS alone, that will require JavaScript.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, I know that, I will deal with that once I get the CSS all sorted out.

Comment: You should probably start by _specifying_ relevant values (all the font properties & line-height) for the textarea, instead of relying on any defaults coming from the user agent stylesheet.

Comment: You cannot put `ol` into the text area but you could make the list in a separate div and to position it over the text area. Remember that according to w3schools "The <textarea> tag defines a multi-line text input control." So you can have only text inside.

Comment: @Azu Yes, I did put the ordered list in a separate div than the textarea. It is in the div with the id of "linenumbersdiv". It is also positioned over the textarea already, although I may move the textarea to the right of where it currently is such that it doesn't automatically overlap with the ordered list div, hense I had put spaces in the example screenshot.

Comment: @CBroe if I could upvote comments, I would upvote yours, as that is helpful.

Comment: I'm afraid such editors are not made with a textarea. It's similar with the editors of mailboxes. They use a div to allow the user type, but then they use Javascript to master it.

Comment: Javascript will, in the future, be used to match the scrolling between the line numbers div and the textarea div. I don't care about any formatting, and such far it has worked well enough for me. I just want the CSS of the ordered list to match that of the textarea.

Comment: I can upvote now, so I just made my first upvote on CBroe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to set the `margin` and `padding`of both `textarea` and the `ol` to 0. Because font properties are not inherited by `textarea`, you need to set them to `inherit`.

```css
.container{
        position: relative; 
        margin: 20px;
        font-family:"Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;
        font-size: 100%;
        line-height: 120%;
    }
    .container .list {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 2;
        width: 25px;
        background-color: green;    
    }
    .container .list ol {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style-position: inside;
        font-family: inherit;
        font-size: inherit;
        line-height: inherit;
    }
    .container .list ol li{
        padding-left:5px;   
    }
    .container .textarea {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
    .container .textarea textarea {     
        width:300px;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0 0 0 30px;
        font-family: inherit;
        font-size: inherit;
        line-height: inherit;
        border: 1px solid black;
        
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="list">
        <ol>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <div class="textarea">
        <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't deny that it works, but at least some sort of explanation in the answer would be nice...

Comment: My post is updated with a proper explanation.

Comment: So that is what I did wrong. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: The solution there removes the font that makes the width of each character the same. I have edited the code and seen that bringing it back brings back the problem. Is there a font that can mimic or bring back the effect?

Comment: I put that font just to make it the same for all sample. No need to copy it.

Comment: I think that copying it is required though, as when I don't, the lines don't line up. But then that brings in the issue of the characters not lining up when I do bring in the font.

Comment: Okay then, please use the new font-family I have placed in my reply. Does it help?

Comment: Where is the said reply?

Comment: The my sample above I chave changed the font to `font-family:"Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace;`.